# How to set mulipart attributes for html helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I want to set a multipart attribute for a `html.Dropdownlist`. How to do this?

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProductTypesId",DropdownHelper.GetAllProductTypes("-1"), new { @class="selectpicker", multiple title = "Select One" })
```

But I have error for the `multiple title` attribute.

**Update**

The error is:

The name multiple doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: What error? Plus, you have a space in that variable name. That is not allowed.

Comment: I have updated the question. But I need to use that attribute. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`multiple title`" is not an attribute in HTML. Attributes are space-separated.

What you have is a single-label attribute "`multiple`" and the *second* attribute "`title="Select one`"

HTML allows for single-label attributes to have their name as a value - this has the same effect and is how XHTML supports single-label attributes, like so:

```
new { @class="selectpicker", multiple="multiple" title="Select One" }
```

this will be rendered like this:

```
<select class="select picker" multiple="multiple" title="Select One">
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can write in htmlAttributes object like that

```
@multiple="multiple"
```